# Ruby Loops Question

Tags: ruby, loops

C++:

```
for(i=0,j=0;i<0;i++,j++)
```

What's the equivalence to this in ruby?

Besides the normal `for`, `while` loop seen in C++. Can someone name off the other special loops ruby has? Such as `.times`? `.each`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `i < 0`? Are you sure?

Comment: You'd probably get more helpful answers if you provided all the code in an example loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby is different to C++. In C++ you use a for loop to loop through anything, but in Ruby you'll find you're usually looping through an enumerable object, so it's more common to do something like:

```
monkeys.each do |monkey|
    monkey.say 'ow!'
end
```

Don't try to look for too much equivalence between the two languages - they're built for different things. Obviously there are a lot of equivalent things, but you can't learn Ruby by producing a chart that shows C++ code on one side and the Ruby equivalent on the other. Try to learn the idiomatic way of doing things and you'll find it much easier.

If you want ways of looping through enumerable objects, check out all the methods in [`Module: Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html): `all?   any?   collect   detect   each_cons   each_slice   each_with_index   entries   enum_cons   enum_slice   enum_with_index   find   find_all   grep   include?   inject   inject   map   max   member?   min   partition   reject   select   sort   sort_by   to_a   to_set   zip`. With most of these methods you'd use a `for` loop to do the equivalent thing in C++.

Comment: If you're working with strings, there are even more each methods -- `each_char` and `each_line` are often handy.

Comment: `each_with_index` is another awesome one :)

Answer (score 9):

If I understand your question (at least the first part of it), you are wondering how you can iterate two separate variables at the same time, such as `i` and `j`.

You can do that in Ruby using the `for` loop, with multiple variables. For instance, if you wanted `i` to count up from 1 to 10, and `j` to count from `10` to `20`, you could do:

```
for i, j in (1..10).zip(10..20)
  puts "#{i}, #{j}"
end
```

`zip` will produce, from two arrays, a single array of which each element is an array, with the first element taken from the corresponding position in the first array, and the second element taken from the corresponding position in the second array:

```
> [1, 2, 3].zip([4, 5, 6])
=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

And using `i, j` in your `for` loop will take `i` from the first element of each inner array, and `j` from the second element.

If you'd rather use `each` than `for`, you can just use a block with two parameters:

```
(1..10).zip(10..20).each { |i, j| puts "#{i}, #{j}" }
```

As to the second part of your question, Ruby doesn't really have a fixed number of different iterators, since most iteration is done by passing a block to a method, and thus any class can define its own methods that allow iterating over its own contents. The most common is `each`, and any class that defines an `each` method can mix in the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) class, which gives you a variety of different methods for iterating over elements, selecting elements, filtering, and so on. There are also `times`, `upto`, and `downto` defined on the [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Integer.html) class, `each_key`, `each_value`, `each_pair` on [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html), `each_byte`, `each_char`, `each_line` on [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html), and so on. Just about any class that defines some sort of collection or sequence has methods for iterating over said collection or sequence.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
(0..j).each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not terribly familiar with C++, but AFAICS, the equivalent Ruby code to the loop you posted is simply:

```
i, j = 0, 0
```

Which shows once again the expressive power Ruby has. *Anybody* can figure out what this does, even if he has never seen Ruby before, while the equivalent C++ takes quite a while to figure out.

Comment: some people (not me) can see it as 3-tuple , with an affectation in the middle, so I prefer the bracketed version [i,j] = [0,0]

Comment: @mb14: That would be `(i, j) = [0, 0]`, but yeah, that's a good point.